# Puppeteer (1.14.0) unable to find anchor tag by "id" although JQuery can find it

Tags: selector, puppeteer

Node v10.15.3 (64-bit)
Puppeteer v1.14.0
Chromium v 75.0.3738.0 (Developer Build) (64-bit)

I am at the very last page of a site automation tool and the last button I need to press (which is actually an anchor tag with an "id" attribute) cannot be found by Puppeteer. The code is:

```
await page2.click('#____bs');
```

The error I receive is:

**Error: Node is either not visible or not an HTMLElement**

The HTML code is here:

```html
<a role="button" ct="Button" rel="tooltip" title="Post" 
    aria-label="Please Select Post" data-toggle="cso-button" id="____bq" 
    class="cso-btn cso-btn cso-action cso-corner cso-btn-primary     " 
    href="javascript:void(0)" 
    data-ctl-options="{'actiontype';:'ACTION','value':'Click'}" 
    style="display: inline-block;">Post</a>
```

While in debug mode with this page up, I can use JQuery to find the element easily:

```
$("#____bq").text()
"Post"
```

Therefore, why can't Puppeteer find it? Is there an alternate way I could try to click this link?

Could it also be that the control (the anchor) is outside the visible edge of the screen? I wouldn't think that would matter since I'm assuming Puppeteer is looking at the HTML and not the screen itself but doesn't hurt to ask.

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: Here's the entire HTML that contains the anchor I'm trying to select:

```html
    <div class="row split">
        <div class="clsFP-expand clsBG-expand cso-hidden cso-cont-50r cso-pad5r">
            <span class="cso-pad5-ie">
    <a role="button" ct="Button" rel="tooltip" title="Cancel" aria-label="Please Select Cancel" data-toggle="cso-button" id="____bo" class="cso-btn cso-btn cso-action cso-corner cso-btn-grey     " href="javascript:void(0)" data-ctl-options="{&quot;actiontype&quot;:&quot;ACTION&quot;,&quot;value&quot;:&quot;Click&quot;}" >Cancel</a>

</span>
            <span class="cso-pad5-ie">
    <a role="button" ct="Button" rel="tooltip" title="Post" aria-label="Please Select Post" data-toggle="cso-button" id="____bs" class="cso-btn cso-btn cso-action cso-corner cso-btn-primary  inactive   " href="javascript:void(0)" data-ctl-options="" >Post</a>


    <a role="button" ct="Button" rel="tooltip" title="Post" aria-label="Please Select Post" data-toggle="cso-button" id="____bq" class="cso-btn cso-btn cso-action cso-corner cso-btn-primary     " href="javascript:void(0)" data-ctl-options="{&quot;actiontype&quot;:&quot;ACTION&quot;,&quot;value&quot;:&quot;Click&quot;}" >Post</a>

</span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Your Puppeteer code references id of `___bs`, while your page contains an id of `___bq`. Which is correct?

Comment: Good catch. Oddly, this page has two anchor tags for the 'Post' "button" one with and id of "____bq and the other with "____bs". This is third-party software so I'm not sure what the difference is. In any event, when I'm in Chrome and use the "Copy Selector" on the button it's "____bq". Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not that Puppeteer is not being able to get the element. That's a validation coming from Puppeteer (see https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/5ee21d97e796263857b9f3fbeaf63366179d346f/lib/JSHandle.js#L203).

According to the doc:

> This method fetches an element with selector, scrolls it into view if needed, and then uses page.mouse to click in the center of the element. If there's no element matching selector, the method throws an error.

That means that Chromium should be able to scroll to that element, and that element should be visible in order to be able to click on it.

Comment: First, thanks for the amazingly quick feedback (to both of you). To your response, hardkoded, I've started Chromium fully maximized and I've turned headless to false so I can see what's happening and I can definitely see the button. I'm wondering now if I injected JQuery (which works at least in the console) to find the element and click it, would that work?

Comment: Yes, you can use jQuery using `evaluate`. That won't simulate a mouse click.

Comment: I added the code surrounding the anchor tag that I'm trying to access. Not sure if the DIVs/SPANs have anything to do with the issue but in case it does I've added the code. Thanks again for your help (both of you ).